# I am trying to hit restful api through resttemplate but i am getting Request processing failed

Tags: resttemplate

error:

```
package com.concretepage.bean;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Quote {

    private String type;
    private Value value;

    public Quote() {
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Value getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Value value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Quote{" +
                "type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", value=" + value +
                '}';
    }
}
```

controller class:

```
package com.concretepage.controller;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.concretepage.bean.Quote;

@Controller
public class LoginController {


    @RequestMapping(value="login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(){
        System.setProperty("proxyHost", "proxy1.wipro.com"); 
        System.setProperty("proxyPort", "8080");
        return "redirect:pages/login.jsp";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="pages/userCheck", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String userCheck(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String name=request.getParameter("name");
        String pwd=request.getParameter("pwd");
        if("concretepage".equalsIgnoreCase(name)&&"concretepage".equalsIgnoreCase(pwd)){

            model.addAttribute("message", "Successfully logged in.");

             RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

             List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters =restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
             MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter map =new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
              messageConverters.add(map);
              restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

                Quote quote = restTemplate.getForObject("http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random", Quote.class);

                System.out.println(quote.toString());


        }else{
            model.addAttribute("message", "Username or password is wrong.");
        }
        return "redirect:success.jsp";
    }

}
```

Qoute class:

```
package com.concretepage.bean;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Quote {

    private String type;
    private Value value;

    public Quote() {
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Value getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Value value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Quote{" +
                "type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", value=" + value +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Error i am getting:message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [com.concretepage.bean.Quote] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]

Comment: Please add the stacktrace to your question using edit function. Not as command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value` might be wrong in `Quote.class` Json object.

Response from the [RequestingURL](http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random)
 you are trying to hit as below.

You have to design your Json object as per the response returned by the server.

```
{
  "type": "success",
  "value": {
   "id": 4,
    "quote": "Previous to Spring Boot, I remember XML hell, confusing set  up,   and many hours of frustration."
 }
}
```

You may have to create another POJO object `Value` with the properties `id` and `quote` and define this as a property in `Quote` class.